# Create partition based in two variables

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a data set with two outcome variables, case1 and case2. Case1 has 4 levels, while case2 has 50 (levels in case2 could increase later). I would like to create data partition for train and test keeping the ratio in both cases. The real data is imbalanced for both case1 and case2. As an example,

```
library(caret)

set.seed(123)
matris=matrix(rnorm(10),1000,20)
case1 <- as.factor(ceiling(runif(1000, 0, 4)))
case2 <- as.factor(ceiling(runif(1000, 0, 50)))

df <- as.data.frame(matris)
df$case1 <- case1
df$case2 <- case2

split1 <- createDataPartition(df$case1, p=0.2)[[1]]
train1 <- df[-split1,]
test1 <- df[split1,]
length(split1)
201

split2 <- createDataPartition(df$case2, p=0.2)[[1]]
train2 <- df[-split2,]
test2 <- df[split2,]
length(split2)
220
```

If I do separate splitting, I get different length for the data frame. If I do one splitting based on case2 (one with more classes), I lose the ratio of classes for case1.

I will be predicting the two cases separately, but at the end my accuracy will be given by having the exact match for both cases (e.g., ix = which(pred1 == case1 & pred2 == case2), so I need the arrays to be the same size.

Is there a smart way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly (which I do not guarantee) I can offer the following approach:

Group by case1 and case2 and get the group indices

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  select(case1, case2) %>%
  group_by(case1, case2) %>%
  group_indices() -> indeces
```

use these indeces as the outcome variable in create data partition:

```
split1 <- createDataPartition(as.factor(indeces), p=0.2)[[1]]
```

check if satisfactory:

```
table(df[split1,22])
#output
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 
 5  6  5  8  5  5  6  6  4  6  6  6  6  6  5  5  5  4  4  7  5  6  5  6  7  5  5  8  6  7  6  6  7 
34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
 4  5  6  6  6  5  5  6  5  6  6  5  4  5  6  4  6

table(df[-split1,22])
#output
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 
15 19 13 18 12 13 16 15  8 13 13 15 21 14 11 13 12  9 12 20 17 15 16 19 16 11 14 21 13 20 18 13 16 
34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
 9  6 12 19 14 10 16 19 17 17 16 14  4 15 14  9 19 

table(df[split1,21])
#output
 1  2  3  4 
71 70 71 67 

table(df[-split1,21])
  1   2   3   4 
176 193 174 178
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for some cases, for others, when the frequency is really low (~10 cases), it gives warning that some classes have single records. I will use, nonetheless, your solution.

Comment: The warning is about group indices and is inherent to the data set.. The lowest sample size for the actual clases is 4 in the example data set.

Comment: Yes, true. I think there is no way of having a good split if the count is low for some classes. I tried your code for other cases, where the count is higher, and it works. Thanks again!